# Correct way to precompile Handlebars template to function, as Jade do it

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

In short, what I need - to precompile programmatically (not CLI) handlebars template to browser-side function and at browser use it with `handlebars.runtime.js` in this way:

```
html = template_as_fn(data_object);
```

Why I need it - I work on YA ComonJS to browser packer tool, [clinch](https://github.com/Meettya/clinch) and I want to support Handlebars too.

So, I looking for correct way to precompile Handlebars template to function, without `eval()` and other voodoo magic.

Things like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129149/manually-use-precompiled-handlebars-templates?rq=1)

```
var data = { name: "Greg" };
var source = "<p>Howdy, {{ name }}</p>";

eval("var templateFunction = " + Handlebars.precompile(source));
var template = Handlebars.template(templateFunction);

template(data);
=> "<p>Howdy, Greg</p>"
```

make me sad.

For example, with Jade I can use [file processor](https://github.com/Meettya/clinch/blob/master/src/file_processor.coffee#L114) in this way

```
'.jade'   : (data, filename, cb) ->
  content = Jade.compile data, _.assign jade_settings, {filename}
  cb null, "module.exports = #{content}"
```

Is it possible to do something like Jade with Handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, nevermind! I find it.

file processor for Handlebars

```
'.handlebars', (data, filename, cb) ->
  content = Handlebars.precompile data
  cb null, "module.exports = #{content}"
```

And in module two-step workaround:

```
renderData : (data) ->
  template_fn = require './template' # /template.handlebars
  template = Handlebars.template template_fn

  res = template data
```

So, from now [clinch](https://github.com/Meettya/clinch) will support Handlebars :)